Is it safe to connect only 2 PCIe 8-pin power connectors to triple PCIe 8-pin to 12VHPWR adapter?
I have a GPU with a 12VHPWR connector that came with a 3xPCIe 8-pin to 16-pin 12VHPWR adapter cable, but my current PSU only has 2 PCIe 6+2 pin connectors on the same cable. Is it safe for me to power the GPU by connecting 2 of the PCIe 6+2 connectors from the GPU to the adapter?
The PSU is a 600W model and the GPU power limit can be configured between 150-350W. The CPU should stay under 100W.
The PSU has a single +12V rail rated for 45A/540W.
I am particularly interested in if it's safe to leave a PCIe 8-pin connector unpopulated on a 12VHPWR adapter.

In order to determine this, the model of the PSU is required since an answer can't be discerned until it's known whether those two PCIe 6+2 connectors are on the same circuit or not, and whether there are any other cables on that same circuit. The PSU's manual will state this, as well as what the max current for that circuit is

@JW0914 thanks, I edited the question to include the information

With the additional info and your specific question, I would contact the GPU OEM and ask their tech support

The PCI-E 6+2 pin cables are rated for 150 Watt each (12V x 12.5A = 150W). So in your case it is able to go to 300 Watts (GPU alone). If your power supply is a good unit from a reliable brand and everything works as intended, specially the overload protection you are save. This doesn't mean that the computer can't shut down under heavy loads duo to the overload protection. When this happens it means that the load was to much and the wise thing to do is to replace the PSU with a one wich has more PCI-E 6+2 pin cables.

This answer isn't correct until it's known whether those two PCIe 6+2 connectors are on the same circuit or not and whether there are any other cables on that same circuit. In order to determine this, the model of the PSU is required.

A single 8-pin connector maximum power delivery is up to 12V * 24A = 288W. But the connector at the GPU is rated for 150W (8-pin) for GPU's.

It doesn't matter what each connector is rated for, as a PSU is manufactured knowing this - what matters is the max current for the PSU circuit those connectors are on and the max current of each component on that circuit. Overload protection only occurs when components have been connected to a PSU without referring to the PSU manual for what the max current is for each PSU circuit, determined by adding up the max current each component is rated for and summing those max current values when components are on the same PSU circuit (separate cables don't mean different circuits)

Is it safe to only connect 2 PCIe 8-pin connectors to a 3xPCIe to 12VHPWR adapter?
